# Edit user's email field in Samba domain

Tags: active-directory, samba, user-management

Looking for a way to update all of my users' email address value in a Samba domain. I have limited knowledge of `samba-tool` and `pdbedit`, but they do not seem to allow command-line editing of a single field. I thought I'd build a script based on:

```
samba-tool user edit --mail-address=newemail@domain.ext username
```

**Is there a way to accomplish this, possibly learning about new tools in the process?**

Answer (score 1):

Open the user config for editing (default is vi, but you can specify alternatives, such as nano with the `--edit` argument

```
samba-tool user edit username
```

Add the following line:

```
mail: newemail@domain.ext
```

substituting the desired email address for *newemail@domain.com*

Then save and exit.
I worked this out by creating a new user with the requisite `--mail-address=` argument and opened that user's config to see what field was added for email.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. What I'm looking for, though, is a non-interactive way to set a field with a command. Something that can be used in a script and change the email address for lots of users.